# Unable to open cordova project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, android-studio

[image]

I try to import my cordova ionic project to eclipse as an existing android application but it was undetectable? Any idea why? I could run my app in android phnoe using 'ionic run android' but why it can be imported to eclipse?

I also installed android studio and it has the same problem. I don't have a clue why is this happens..

Comment: The question is why would you need to open a ionic/cordova project in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `CordovaLib` that exists inside eclipse and import it again. It works 100% most of the time. Second time you import the project you will enable import your project with `CordovaLib`. It happens because there are existing `CordovaLib` inside your eclipse.

Comment: remove project myApp and import again one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose the platforms/android folder when you want to import in eclipse, not the root of your project.
Eclipse only knows the android project, but not the cordova project.

And then select both your app and the CordovaLib projects.

But be aware that changes made in /www will only take effect in eclipse after you rebuid the project.

Or you can use eclipse project properties to unhide assets/www an in that case be aware that any changes in assets/www will be lost if you use the cli to build your project (and the same goes for any change in platform/android).

That's why I only use eclipse when I need to debug (mostly for plugins).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a very same issue,
Please make sure - you are **importing the project using already existing android code under the Android** tab in import option. Not with already existing project option in general. This one fixed my issue,

Hopes this one will help some to save some valuable time ...